# An analysis of a sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I just wonder if anyone could help me understand the differences between the following original excerpt gleaned from the latest *The Economist* as follows :

> One aspect of hammam culture **proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and covid-19** is its role in wedding rituals.

and the following sentence:

> One aspect proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and covid-19 **of hammam culture** is its role in wedding rituals.

In the first, original, excerpt, my dilemma in understanding is whether **proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and covid-19** is referred to one aspect or hammam culture; in the second, I can clearly understand which one has been referred to which is one aspect.

Comment: No. There's no syntactic rule that allows the sentence to be split like that, so it's ungrammatical whether you understand it or not.  _Aspect_ **is** the culture, or at least part of it, so they can't be distinguished. Aspects don't exist without what they are part of.

Comment: Prepositional phrases are notoriously mobile, but in this case the original works a lot better.

Comment: Is *what's* role in wedding rituals? You've basically said: *one resistant aspect is its role in wedding rituals*. I think you mean: *one resistant aspect is wedding rituals*. ***One aspect of hammam culture [that proves] resistant to the pressures of both modernity and covid-19 is wedding rituals.***

Answer (score 2):

Unless one gets into the semantics of the sentence, it's difficult to analyze its syntax. A cursory Google search tells me that **hammam culture** centers around the the practice of steam bathing in the muslim tradition.

I don't see any difficulty with parsing the first sentence. It parses just fine:

> One aspect of hammam culture proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and Covid-19 is its role in wedding rituals.

Or

> One aspect of *A* proving resistant to the pressures of both *B and C* is its role in *D*.

For the sake of convenience, I've substituted *A*, *B*, *C*, and *D* for **hammam culture**, **modernity**, **Covid-19**, and **wedding rituals.**

Please note that the *gerund phrase*  **proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and Covid-19** modifies the noun phrase **one aspect** ( which is modified further by the PP *of hammam culture*.)

Consider now

> One aspect proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and Covid-19 of hammam culture is its role in wedding rituals.

This could be parsed as:

> One aspect proving resistant to the pressure of modernity and to the pressure of Covid-19 of hammam culture is its role in wedding rituals.

I don't think that's the intended meaning. What could *Covid-19* of *hammam culture* mean?

In other words, the second sentence doesn't make any meaning because of a misplaced modifier.

*ASIDE*>>

*The Economist* puts out top-hole articles and columns. They couldn't possibly bungle their sentences.

Comment: Totally concur with your points succinctly summarized. However, the issue that I am trying to get my head around is which one modifying gerund is referred to :                                                                                                    
One aspect of hammam culture proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and Covid-19 is its role in wedding rituals. Cannot we just use the following one that directly modifies the "one aspect"?
One aspect proving resistant to the pressures of both modernity and covid-19 of hammam culture is its role in wedding rituals.